# How to omit from showing in output empty results

Tags: r, shiny

Created a shiny app for users to upload their timeseries dataframes and calculate outliers in each row of the uploaded dataframe separately.

The problem: in the mainpanel the output shows every rows outlier results, but I only need the ones that are not numeric(0). Show only the ones that have outliers and the dataframe row number in which the outliers appeared.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Outlier analysis"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("Data",
                        "Upload file:")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          verbatimTextOutput("Outliers")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
      options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
  
      mydata <- reactive({
        data <- input$Data
        data <- read_excel(data$datapath, col_names=FALSE)
        data <- data[-(1:2),]
        names(data) <- data[1,]
        data <- data[-1,]
        data <- data[,-1]
        data <- data.frame(data)
        })
      
      f <- function(data){
        x <- na.omit(as.numeric(data))
        mean <- mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm=T)
        sd <-   sd(as.numeric(x), na.rm=T)
        Tmin <- mean - (3*sd)
        Tmax <- mean + (3*sd)
        return(x[which(x < Tmin | x > Tmax)])
      }
      output$Outliers <- renderPrint({
        apply(mydata(), 1, f)
      })
}
```

**Output**:

```
[[1]]
numeric(0)

... 

[[30]]
numeric(0)

[[31]]
numeric(0)

[[32]]
numeric(0)

[[33]]
numeric(0)

[[34]]
numeric(0)

[[35]]
[1] 682.231 692.713 698.037 716.197 735.422

[[36]]
numeric(0)

...
```

Desired output would be this:

```
[[35]]
[1] 682.231 692.713 698.037 716.197 735.422

[[51]]
[1] 682.231 692.713 698.037 716.197 735.422

[[66]]
[1] 682.231 692.713 698.037 716.197 735.422

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `renderPrint` statement to the following.

```
output$Outliers <- renderPrint({
  res <- apply(mydata(), 1, f)
  res[lengths(res) > 0]
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for showing only the values that are outliers, but then the row in which are the outliers, is not shown.  `[[1]]
[1] 682.231 692.713 698.037 716.197 735.422

[[2]]
[1] 682.231 692.713 698.037 716.197 735.422

[[3]]
[1] 682.231 692.713 698.037 716.197 735.422

[[4]]
[1] 72312.37

...`